# Code Sign error after renewing my certificate

Tags: iphone, code-signing, renewal

my certificate has just expired.
I renewed it on Team section, then renew provisioning profile, and reinstall them on my keychain and xcode, and then I get this error :

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the login keychain

What should I do ?

Thanks a lot

Thierry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
I have erased my private key.

I had to request 'CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest' certifcate using keychain which create a new private key.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your password for your computer after you have already created a cert, you will have to go through the process all over again and create new certs. Took me 4 hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to add that you'll receive this error when your certificate is expired or when it is somehow removed from your keychain. To fix it, login to iPhone developer program portal and renew the certificate - the instructions there are pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Erasing your private key is not enough.

You must also delete your provisioning profile from your Mac, otherwise the new profile will (silently!) fail to install, even though it is clearly newer than the existing one.

(erasing key is easiest using the iPhone Configuration Utility, which you can download from Apple.com. Erasing profile is easiest using that app too. Everyone should get iPCU! (it's free))

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is answered, but if anyone is having issues with this and isn't sure where to look for information - I find the following useful:

You can also check the status of your provisioning certificates in the provisioning section  on the development and distribution tabs.

This is useful, as if the certificates have changed or there was a problem with the generation, then the existing application provisioning profile(s) status will be marked as invalid. You'll have to modify them anyway in this case, but I found it useful.

Additionally in XCode, the Organizer window under
iPhone Development->Provisioning Profiles 
is a quick way to see any issues, especially with expiration dates.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen also if WWDR intermediate certificate is not installed.